# vim: discard pending keyboard input

Tags: input, keyboard, vim

## Background:

I'm writing a fuzzy-finding vim plugin which runs a graphical program as a separate process. It opens a window, you type into it, press return, and then the vim plugin processes its output and navigates to the file / buffer you selected.

The time between triggering the find function and the new process grabbing keyboard input is a fraction of a second, so it's possible to accidentally type too soon, which causes that input to be delivered to vim.

Given that vim is single-threaded, I know (and have verified) that the errant keyboard input is not actually processed until the program finishes - the input is buffered while the program runs, and afterwards the random keys I typed are interpreted as vim actions.

## Question:

**How can I discard input that's sitting in vim's input buffer but has not yet been processed?**

`inputsave()` takes pending keyboard input and saves it onto a stack. This would be what I want, except that it causes a memory leak if I don't match it with a call to `inputrestore()`. Is it possible to discard the stored input without executing it?

If that's not directly possible, can anyone think of a good way to discharge those events into a safe place? i.e call `inputrestore()` in such a state that the stored input will have no visible effect.

I need to do this in both a normal-mode mapping, and a command-mode mapping. So I'd prefer a solution which doesn't abandon the current command-mode input.

Comment: If this only happens occasionally by accident, I wouldn't care much about those few leaked keys' memory. If this happens often, redesign your workflow, e.g. by querying inside Vim.

Comment: I believe the the memory leak happens whether or not there actually _is_ any pending input - so in order to prevent the occasional sporadic input, I need to take a hit every time the plugin is invoked. It may never cause me to run out of memory, but it still feels dirty...